# Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I'm using [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem for searching in my rails app.

It was working fine but suddenly getting this error the next day on searching.

[image: the error]

Comment: problem solved! i had to restart the elasticsearch plugin to get it working!

Comment: That is not how you should solve the issue, because it will eventually come back and you still don't have a solution ... right ? I suggest to investigate "memory leak"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all those who find this and might be wondering how to restart the elasticsearch plugin:

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
```

worked for me.

Comment: That is not how you solve the issue (see my comment upstairs to  Manoj Selvam

Comment: Actually you are wrong.  This is how I solved the issue.  In my case it had nothing to do with a memory leak - just some server parameters had changed.

Comment: which parameters and which server (OS, HW, ammount of mem) if I can ask ? ... anyway I agree that a reboot can solve many issues ... until they will come back :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner and group of

```
/etc/elasticsearch
```

. By default ES_USER and ES_GROUP is elasticsearch. So if the owner/group of the mentioned directory is not in ES_USER or ES_GROUP they will not be having privileges to access 9200 port, it may throw this error.

Comment: Dheeraj, i know this post is old, but may i asked how to do that on mac please ?

Answer (score 0):

Error message:

> Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200

The error message indicates that elasticsearch is not running. To start elastic search on linux, run the following command:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

I hope this post helps. Happy coding! :)